# How to properly use an "images" subdirectory in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Seems like this should be pretty simple, but I'm finding it frustratingly difficult to get right. Rather than jam all my images into my project's base directory, I'm placing them in a subdirectory named "images". However when I try to load an image from this directory, I receive:

> ERROR: bad argument #2 to display.newImageRect(): width expected, but got string.

```
local background = display.newImageRect( "menu-bg.jpg", "images/", 570, 360 )
```

From the [docs](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html), I don't see any problems with the syntax. Is this a bug with the display library, or the docs, or am I handling the baseDir property wrong (and seeing a wonky error message)?

Answer (score 2):

Ok after fiddling with this some more, it looks like I can append the path to the filename, e.g.

```
local background = display.newImageRect( "images/menu-bg.jpg", 570, 360 )
```

In other words, I misunderstood the meaning of "baseDir".

Comment: Looking at the docs you mistook the type for baseDir.  It says it is a constant vs. a string (what you used in your first example).

It looks like it has to be one of these:  
`system.CachesDirectory`
`system.DocumentsDirectory`
`system.ResourceDirectory`
`system.TemporaryDirectory`

So yeah, I thought it would have meant a base directory of images, but it seems to be talking deeper with where the files are stored on the actual device.